# После копирования File.Copy файл обрабатывается медленно

Tags: c#, .net

Уважаемые Господа!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Копирую файл `SourceFile` в `DestFile` с помощью

```
File.Copy(SourceFile, DestFile, true);
```

Само копирование проходит отлично, но далее работа с файлом `SourceFile` с помощью `FileStream` происходит с заметным замедлением! Через секунд 20, если не использовать этот файл, работа становится снова быстрой.

Оба файла `SourceFile` и `DestFile` находятся в одной сетевой папке.
Суть задачи в том, что мне нужно перед некоторыми операциями над файлом сделать его бэкап в ту же папку. Проблемы нет, когда папка локальная, но когда сетевая, встает эта проблема.

Может что-то с кешированием файловой системы по сети?

Когда я использую для копирования ручной метод чтения - записи в файловые потоки, то проблем с замедлением конечно нет, но правда само копирование (бэкап) идет дольше. Для этого я и хотел использовать `File.Copy`, чтобы не создавать трафик в сети...

Буду рад помощи!
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Ручное копирование медленнее ровно на длительность задержки после применения File.Copy. Все логично, даром ни чего не бывает, тем более при работе с сетью. Ну и да, в исходники WinAPI конечно не лазил, но думаю при сетевом копировании применяется буфер, чтобы освободить файл-источник как можно скорее, т.к. передача данных по сети может быть долгой

Comment: В общем я так и предполагал, но...
File.Copy - функция вроде как синхронная. Соответственно, я по идее могу расчитывать на то, что после ее выполнения все нужные ей ресурсы освобождены. 
И потом, я надеялся, что нет необходимости действительно что то копировать, а достаточно только послать команду удаленному компьютеру(ведь оба файла находятся на одном удаленном компе), дождаться исполнения и вернуть мне управление.
Если все это не так, то печалька.
Хорошо, что новый FileStream.CopyTo работает заметно лучше старого ручного подхода...

Answer (score 0):

Код функции File.Copy:

```
public static void Copy(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
{
  if (sourceFileName == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("sourceFileName", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_FileName"));
  if (destFileName == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("destFileName", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_FileName"));
  if (sourceFileName.Length == 0)
    throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyFileName"), "sourceFileName");
  if (destFileName.Length == 0)
    throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyFileName"), "destFileName");
  File.InternalCopy(sourceFileName, destFileName, false, true);
}
```

откуда вызывается:

```
internal static string InternalCopy(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, bool overwrite, bool checkHost)
{
  string fullPathInternal1 = Path.GetFullPathInternal(sourceFileName);
  string fullPathInternal2 = Path.GetFullPathInternal(destFileName);
  FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, fullPathInternal1, false, false);
  FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, fullPathInternal2, false, false);
  if (!Win32Native.CopyFile(fullPathInternal1, fullPathInternal2, !overwrite))
  {
    int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    string maybeFullPath = destFileName;
    if (lastWin32Error != 80)
    {
      using (SafeFileHandle file = Win32Native.UnsafeCreateFile(fullPathInternal1, int.MinValue, FileShare.Read, (Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) null, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero))
      {
        if (file.IsInvalid)
          maybeFullPath = sourceFileName;
      }
      if (lastWin32Error == 5 && Directory.InternalExists(fullPathInternal2))
        throw new IOException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_FileIsDirectory_Name", (object) destFileName), 5, fullPathInternal2);
    }
    __Error.WinIOError(lastWin32Error, maybeFullPath);
  }
  return fullPathInternal2;
}
```

Как видно, используется Win32 функция CopyFile, в связи с этим, когда функция File.Copy уже закончила работу, файл еще фактически мог быть не скопирован операционной системой. Когда вы напрямую копируете через потоки, этого не происходит, видимо, копирование происходит сразу. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь пояснит подробнее.

Comment: А где вы нашли этот код?

Comment: При помощи декомпилятора dotPeek в сборке C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll. Net Framework v4.6.1

Comment: Вот, к примеру, System.IO.FileStream.Read: https://pastebin.com/yi1AeFkU - сразу видно, функция делом занята.

Comment: @Philippe этот же код вы можете посмотреть в открытых исходниках  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,4a0905e7dc32d77d